# C# static method refactoring

Tags: c#, refactoring

Can anybody help me with refactoring of such methods:

```
public static void MethodA(this SceneObject obj, double value)
public static void MethodA(this SceneObject obj, long value)
public static void MethodA(this SceneObject obj, int value)

public static void MethodB(this IEnumerable<MyData> sObjects, IEnumerable<int> values)
public static void MethodB(this IEnumerable<MyData> sObjects, IEnumerable<long> values)
```

How can I make them one generic method that can take any kind of param? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) feature.

```
public static void MethodA<T>(this SceneObject obj, T value)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SceneObject.MethodA<long>(50);
Sceneobject.MethodA<int>(50);
```

The `value` parameter automatically gets the type of T. So in this case `long` or `ìnt`.

Answer (score 2):

If your question just is about how to make your definition generic, it could be done like:

```
public static void Method<T>(this object, T value)
```

If you want to be able to use it on all kind of objects or not you may want to adjust the type you are extending.

The usage would then be:

```
someObject.Method<int>(1);
someObject.Method<long>(1);
someObject.Method<double>(1);

someObject.Method<List<int>>(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
```

If you would like to have a numeric constraint you could also do something like:

```
public static void Method<T>(this object, T value) : where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void MethodA<T>(this SceneObject obj, T value) where T : struct 

public static void MethodB<T>(this IEnumerable<MyData> sObjects, IEnumerable<T> values) where T : struct
```